# reflux.listento works wrong for me

Tags: reactjs, react-router, refluxjs

I am building an front app using react and reflux,react-router and using browserify.

and I got a console message.

> [object Object] is missing a listen method

Do you know why i got a exception like this??

Component

```
var TrendSearchBox = React.createClass({
mixins: [Reflux.listenTo(BroadcastStore, "onCategoryUpdate")],
onCategoryUpdate: function() {

},
render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Input type="select" label="select1" multiple onChange={this._getTitles} ref="categoryIds">
            </Input>
            <Input type="select" label="select2" multiple ref="titleIds">
            </Input>
            <ButtonInput type="submit" value="search" bsStyle="primary" bsSize="large" className="btn-block"/>
        </div>
    );
},
_getTitles: function() {}
```

});

Store

```
var BroadcastStore = Reflux.createStore({
listenables: BroadcastActions,
onCategoryUpdate: function() {
    console.log('1');
},

onResultUpdate: function() {
    console.log('2');
}
});
```

action

```
var BroadcastActions = Reflux.createActions([
    "categoryUpdate",
    "resultUpdate"
]);
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. Are these the only component, store, and actions in you app? I.E. could the error be coming from somewhere else?